# Reopen request: Does mentioning a company name automatically make a question company-specific?

Tags: bug, reopen-request

[Vacation days not paid](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/121297/vacation-days-not-paid)

This question asks about how to get paid for vacation days after being fired from an employer.

Now Hardee's may or may not have a policy regarding this.  They're a big company; they probably do.  But an answer to this question could be useful to anyone wondering how (if even possible) to get vacation days paid out after leaving any employer or being fired.  Answers could touch on the legalities of the situation, the importance of reviewing company policy documents, interpersonal methods for resolving the situation with the company's HR...

Answers *could* touch on these things, but they won't, because as with most questions here, the close-question gang came along and, as usual, found it easier to close a question than to edit it or offer comment suggestions as to how it could be improved (or even so much as an explanation of specifically what they found wrong with it).

It should be reopened as-is.  The mere fact that a company name is mentioned does not *de facto* make a question company-specific.

Comment: Even if the company wasn't mentioned, it still depends on the company policies. For example if I put an answer saying X and then another person tried using that in their own experience... it may not have the same effect simply due to company policies

Comment: plus the question you have marked lacks severe detail, as stated on the comments. The question is not closed but is on hold till we are provided with the details. For now I completely agree it should be on hold.

Comment: "*It should be reopened as-is*" Strongly disagree. Without a location it's impossible to answer. Each state has different rules on this. "*Are vacation days paid out in State X?*" is answerable. "*How can I ask my employer to pay out my vacation days when they're not legally required to*?" is also a good question. The linked question needs work.

Comment: @Lilienthal, how about adding a comment to the original question to help the user know how he/she could edit the question to be more acceptable?

Comment: @Twyxz, so how about adding a comment to the original question?  That would help the user to know how to make the question acceptable, and would be a nice _positive_ step to balance out the negative step of closing it.

Comment: @Kyralessa Someone else already did so.

Comment: I voted to reopen.

Answer (score 3):

With a location this would be answerable in my view.. the rules regarding paying out accrued vacation time vary from "they have to pay you by X date" to "they can do whatever they want" but it's not company specific by any means.

Comment: (Wikipedia)[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardee%27s] says Hardee's is an "American based fast-food restaurant chain". I suppose US is the answer then :)

Comment: @Cyonis Yep, it's likely to be in the US but there's massive variance by state and they also have Hardee's branded locations in other countries - *"specifically in Bahrain, Curaçao, Egypt, El Salvador, Guatemala, Hong Kong, Iraq, Jamaica, Jordan, Kazakhstan, Kuwait, Lebanon, Oman, Pakistan, Qatar, Saudi Arabia, South Korea, Taiwan and the United Arab Emirates"*

Comment: Ah, I'm not that familiar with US laws. I provided an edit, hopefully it is answerable now. If state is needed, we'll need to wait for OP to return.

Comment: @Cyonis yep state is important if it is in the US